# cannot confirm after passing the LinkedIn API authorisation on iPhone App

Tags: objective-c, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I have done the authorisation step of [LinkedIn-iphone API](http://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone), and the app comes to the screenshot:

---

[image: where to use the LinkedIn PIN]

But the 'close' button does not respond, and no where to use the authorised PIN.

Because it is not finally authorised, the methods like

```
- (void)linkedInEngine:(RDLinkedInEngine *)engine requestSucceeded:(RDLinkedInConnectionID *)identifier withResults:(id)results {
 NSLog(@"++ LinkedIn engine reports success for connection %@\n%@", identifier, results);
}

- (void)linkedInAuthorizationControllerSucceeded:(RDLinkedInAuthorizationController *)controller {
 NSLog(@"Authentication succeeded.");
 NSLog(@"Fetching current user's profile on connection %@", [controller.engine profileForCurrentUser]);
 [rdEngine updateStatus:@"when can you update me??"];
}
```

do not run.

So the LinkedIn API is stuck there.

Anyone find the problem and solution please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application will require you to fill in your API and Secret keys from LinkedIn. Your
app should be designated as a mobile application, and the OAuth Redirect URL *must* be set to:
 http://linkedin_oauth/success

Comment: I have the API and secret keys ("authorized GRACENav" in the screenshot). Could you show the example code where I should put the "http://linkedin_oauth/success" as OAuth Redirect URL in my .m please?

Comment: Thanks I got what you said. The OAuth Redirect URL should be put in the application on LinkedIn web site, not in the iPhone App itself. Now the [rdEngine updateStatus:@"string"] can update LinkedIn activity. But seems the status only allow 140 characters like Twitter.

Comment: Just to clarify, as the App Details page in LinkedIn Network says,  That parameter is only used if you do not pass in the oauth_callback parameter in the requestToken call. If you use a toolkit or lib to access linkedIn you can check if there is a way to set the callback there if you want (perhaps a constructor, a setter, etc).

Answer (score 1):

When I go to the LinkedIn Auth Screen, I get a truncated view of the Linkedin screen.

I have entered The OAuth Redirect URL  in the application on LinkedIn web site.
I am also identifying the app as a mobile app.

Best Regards, Somnath